# GoToRecord Runtime Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

wrote a code to check if a special issue already exist and if so goes there.
The code is actually working fine but as soon as j = 1 there is an error after the correct record is showing. So basically the code works but as soon as I deselect the field the error appears.
Runtime error 2105 - You can't go to the specified record

So my error is caused by the condition then j = 1. But that's wrong there.

```
Private Sub txtnmb_LostFocus()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim SearchNmb As Long
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblNumber")

' Function to prevent to check existing records
If Me.txtOpenDate.Value <> Date And (Len(Nz(Me.txt_History_W)) <> 0 Or Len(Nz(Me.txt_Q_Desc_History)) <> 0 Or Len(Nz(Me.txt_S_History)) = False Or Len(Nz(Me.txt_P_history)) <> 0) Then
    Exit Sub
End If

If Len(Nz(Me.txtnmb.Value)) <> 0 Then
    SearchNmb = Me.txtnmb.Value
    j = 0
    ' Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        ' Moves to the first record and checks every record for matching the new issue
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs.EOF = True
            If rs![Nmb] = SearchNmb Or rs![Nmb_Alternative] = SearchNmb Then
                Me.Undo
                i = 0
                j = 1
            End If
            i = i + 1
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        ' If there is a matching record it goes there
        If j = 1 Then
            DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "Adding Form", acPrevious, i
        End If
    End If

End If

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

End Sub

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like there are so many things to change in your code. First the choice of your event. Lost Focus is Triggered everytime the control gets and looses focus. But by the understanding of what you have written I take this is a Number you enter in a "new record". So it should check the table if the record exist. If it does, should not add the new record, but land you there so you can continue to edit it. In that case you need the BeforeUpdate event.

Next is the Recordset object. You do not need to loop through the recordset object. You can simply use the FindFirst method, after performing a simple DCount on the table.

```
Private Sub txtnmb_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim SearchNmb As Long

    ' Function to prevent to check existing records
    If Not Me.NewRecord Then Exit Sub

    If Len(Nz(Me.txtnmb)) <> 0 Then
        SearchNmb = Me.txtnmb
        If DCount("*", "tblNumber", "Nmb = " & SearchNmb & " OR Nmb_Alternative = " & SearchNmb) <> 0 Then
            Cancel = True
            With Me.Recordset
                .FindFirst "Nmb = " & SearchNmb & " OR Nmb_Alternative = " & SearchNmb
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks PaulFrancis, I have to admit that makes the code a lot leaner. But the code isn't working fully for my problem yet since the criteria of DCount causes a problem regarding the spaces in the names of the parameters. You just wrote Nmb_Alternative but that gives out a syntax error. Any idea?

Comment: You're most welcome ! If this has actually solved your problem, feel free to mark it as answer, so others may be benefited by this. Good luck.

Comment: Hey thanks PaulFrancis, I have to admit that makes the code a lot leaner. But the code isn't working fully for my problem yet since the criteria of DCount causes a problem regarding the spaces in the names of the parameters. You just wrote Nmb_Alternative but that gives out a syntax error. Any idea? I will then certainly mark it as helpful. But this is also a general problem I sometime have - would you recommend in this way to leave to spaces between the letter?

Comment: Is Nmb_Alternative the column name or Nmb Alternative? Also the Data type of the field is still Long right? If it has spaces in the field name, enclose them in square brackets. like [Nmb Alternative]. If the field is a Text type you need to wrap it in Single quotes. Like, [Nmb Alternative] = '" & SearchNmb & "'". No I would never recommend spaces in field names.